# C sqrt == long int

Tags: c++, floating-accuracy

I don't know why if I have the following code:

```
int main() {
    long int height_cat, number_worker_cats, number_helper_cats, height_tree;
    bool flag;
    scanf("%ld%ld", &height_cat, &number_worker_cats);
    for (number_helper_cats = 1; ; ++number_helper_cats) {
        for (height_tree = 1; (long int)pow(number_helper_cats + 1, height_tree) <= height_cat; ++height_tree) {
            if ((long int)(pow(number_helper_cats + 1, height_tree) - height_cat) == 0 && (long int)(pow(number_helper_cats, height_tree) - number_worker_cats) == 0) {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            break;
        }
    }
 printf("%ld, %ld\n", number_helper_cats, height_tree);
}
```

I'm searching for `number_helper_cats` and `height_tree` which `(number_helper_cats +1)^height_tree = height_cat` and `number_helper_cats^height_tree = number_worker_cats` where `height_cat` and `number_worker_cats` are `integers`.

For example if `height_cat = 216` and `number_worker_cats = 125`, the code will stop on `number_helper_cats = 5` and `height_tree = 3` since `(5+1)^3 = 216` and `5^3 = 125`.

But if I have the following code it doesnt work, loops forever, why?

```
int main() {
    long int height_cat, number_worker_cats, number_helper_cats, height_tree;
    bool flag;
    scanf("%ld%ld", &height_cat, &number_worker_cats);
    for (number_helper_cats = 1; ; ++number_helper_cats) {
        for (height_tree = 1; pow(number_helper_cats + 1, height_tree) <= height_cat; ++height_tree) {
            if ((long int)(pow(number_helper_cats + 1, height_tree)) == height_cat &&
                        (long int)(pow(number_helper_cats, height_tree)) == number_worker_cats) {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            break;
        }
    }
printf("%ld, %ld\n", number_helper_cats, height_tree);
}
```

Everything is `long int` and every height_cat and number_worker_cats for testcase are true for the operations, another example height_cat = 5764801, number_worker_cats = 1679616, number_helper_cats = 6 and height_tree = 8 because (6 + 1)^8 = 5764801, 6^8 = 1679616. But again the first code runs well, and the second one loops forever. pow are precise I mean 6^3 = 216 and 5^3 = 125 right? :p

Comment: At least tell us which loop is infinite. And I bet that once you have figured that out, you'll know the answer.

Comment: @MSalters It seems clear (I think anyway) that the outer loop is the one going forever: Once you hit a certain number of helper cats the inner loop won't even iterate, preventing flag from ever being set.

Comment: The code (well I had to add a bunch of boilerplate to get it to compile) terminates just fine with g++ 4.5 and no optimization, `-O2`, `-O3`, and even `-O3 -ffast-math`. Please give us a complete example that we can compile and run to exhibit the problem as well as which compiler and architecture you're on.

Comment: @Mark B I just put the complete code for both cases

Comment: @user1827024 Looks like a good job for a debugger. Or, if you don't have a debugger, use the following idea: `if (number_helper_cats == 6 and height_tree == 8) printf("%ld\n", (long int)(pow(number_helper_cats + 1, height_tree)));`

Comment: @anatolyg I tried with that and its ok, the code doesnt stop. pow(7, 8) = 5764801, not 5764800.99999999

Answer (score 1):

The result of `pow` is `double`, and `double` numbers are not precise in a lot of cases. To test equality with a `double`, a common method would be

```
if (abs(pow(number_helper_cats + 1, height_tree) - height_cat)) < 0.001); // 0.001 is an arbitrary small number
{
     ...
}
```

Aand for test for `<=`, you should use `pow(number_helper_cats + 1, height_tree) <= height_cat + 0.001` .

However, I must mention that you code cannot produce the infinite loop you mentioned in your quesiton with my gcc 4.7.2 . All your loops just end normally.

Comment: "double numbers are never precise". This is patently untrue. In particular, `double(216)` and `double(125)` ARE precise. If anything, `pow()` isn't precise but even that would surprise me here.

Comment: Actually `double` can exactly represent a wide variety of integral values. Without knowing the inputs it's hard to say if this is the problem.

Comment: @MSalters Well, I made a strong statement here, I'll try to rephrase it. But I do believe pow would not produce a precise result, as it should not have a special algorithm written for ingtegers.

Comment: @fefe: In implementations I have seen, it _did_ have such an integer-specific algorithm.

Comment: @fefe But I am doing the cast to long int, anyway the second code is not working, but the first one

Comment: @user1827024 in casting to `long int`, the fraction part is truncated. That means, 0.9999999999... would become 0, but not 1. So the cast does not help much.

Comment: @fefe but pow(7, 8) = 5764801, not 5764800.99999999